# Update app in Google Play store

Tags: android

I have an app published in the Google Play store. I have updated the design of the icons and want to upload the app with the new changes to the store.

I have read on tutorials that I have to change the app version in the manifest. I have checked my original manifest file, and it does not show the following lines in it.

> android:versionCode="2" 
>   android:versionName="1.1">

Can I just add them now to the manifest and upload new apk, even though there is already a published version of the app in the store?

Thanks.

Comment: is there app with same version code?

Comment: Check your `gradle.build` file if you're using Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your app is developed in Android Studio. In Android Studio, version name and version code are added in the `build.gadle` (Module App) file instead of AndroidMenifest.xml

You have to add the version detail in your build.gradle like below:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.augmedix.www.animatevoice"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check your AndoridManifest.xml. Inside this file there must be a mainfest tag. In this tag there are two attributes

1). android:versionCode
2). android:versionName

Here every time when you update your app its mandatory to increase the VersionCode but its optional to increase the VersionName. 
Also, if you are using AndroidStudio, you can check the answer given by @Arman.

Hope it will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on **Android Studio** goto **build.gradle** (Module app) file and change the **versionCode** and versionName(optional). And then sync project and generate signed apk with existing keystore and upload to production in play store.